# "Multi-"indexing elements in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am writing an R code with three loops to produce a large number of matrices and I wish to store all these matrices. The task is that for each 200 large matrices, I take a 10 by 10 sub matrix each time from left to right and from top to bottom. All these (200*790*790) matrices of size (10*10) are what I want. The following is what I have already done:

```
# Define an empty list to store all submatrices
sub.matrix = list() 

# for loop to generate and store all submatrices
for(i in 1:200){
  for(j in 1:790){
    for(k in 1:790){
       sub.matrix[[i]][[j]][[k]] = main.matrix[[i]][j:(j+10), k:(k+10)] # QUESTION STARTS AT THE BEGINNING OF THIS LINE. 
    }
  }
}
```

So the main question is how I could effectively index the sub.matrix. I though it should be as above "[[i]][[j]][[k]]", but the computer told me the error

> Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : subscript out of bounds.

How could I solve this issue or is there any other way of "multi-" indexing the matrices in such a list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `main.matrix` get defined?

Comment: @Hack-R They are multiple matrices read from my laptop.

Comment: Right I just mean that on StackOverflow's R tag we require a *reproducible* example...

Answer (score 0):

Your `sub.matrix` needs to be initialized before you can index it:

```
x <- list()
x[[1]]
```

> Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

The error happens when you try to index an empty list, try the following instead (but I doubt your computer has enough memory to hold the object):

```
sub.matrix = vector(mode = "list", length = 200) 
for(i in 1:200){
    sub.matrix[[i]] = vector(mode = "list", length = 790)
    for(j in 1:790){
        sub.matrix[[i]][[j]] = vector(mode = "list", length = 790)
        for(k in 1:790){
            sub.matrix[[i]][[j]][[k]] = main.matrix[[i]][j:(j+10), k:(k+10)] 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and I will try this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hmm... Is it because the number of matrices is too large so that after I run the code, after about 15 minute, R just terminate due to some fatal error. :(

Comment: It probably is. Some rough estimation, maybe wrong, your data takes around 600GB in memory. Try on a small data set.

Comment: Probably I'll try to divide the first loop into small pieces.